# Как пингануть две разные сети в одном vlan?

Tags: сеть, cisco

Вопрос в том что у меня есть 2 пк, 2 роутера. у одно пк сеть 10.10.10.254 у другого 10.0.10.12. Маска 24(255.255.255.0) На коммутаторах настроены vlan . Мне надо пингануть две разные сети но они находятся в одном влане. Что нужно сделать ? если нужна схема или сеть. Могу скинуть. Коммутаторы Cisco

Comment: *Что нужно сделать ?* Пинговать с узла (компьютера), подключенного в тот же VLAN и имеющего на интерфейсе адреса из обеих подсетей.

Comment: @Akina  да . есть еще роутер с настройками саба 
interface Ethernet0/0.10
 description VLAN-10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 10.0.10.254 255.255.255.0

думаю тут надо что то сделать